# Insert new block to product.info doesn't work

Tags: magento, block

I have created two new blocks, which should be output before and after this block:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
```

To do this I've created a new module, which updates the layout. In the refered XML file stands this:

```
<catalog_product_view>
  <reference name="product.info">
    <block type="disablecartonlogout/output" name="disablecartonlogout.outputbefore" as="whatever" before="product.info.addtocart" template="disablecartonlogout/product-options-bottom-before.phtml" />
    <block type="disablecartonlogout/output" name="disablecartonlogout.outputafter" as="whatever" after="product.info.addtocart" template="disablecartonlogout/product-options-bottom-after.phtml" />
  </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

I get no output. 
If I change the reference to "content", the blocks will be outputted, but on the wrong position.

Can you tell me, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: are you calling the block in templates?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I would like to call my block like written in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly call your blocks in the `product.info` block template (that should be `catalog/product/view.phtml`), at the place you want.

The method you want to use only works for some specific blocks (usually, `core/text_list` or `core/template` doing an empty `getChildHtml()` call, what's not the case of `product.info`)

Comment: Yes thanks, I am currently in this view.phtml and I see what you mean. I really don't want to touch core files, so is there maybe a possibility to replace the whole "product.info.addtocart" block with my block, which contains the original block again? So i could wrap something arround.

Comment: To wrap the original HTML into your own, you can use an observer on the `core_block_abstract_to_html_after` event, dispatched in `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::toHtml()`. Whenever the given block is named `product.info.addtocart` (and if necessary, when the current action corresponds to what you want), you could then use the `transport` object to update the HTML result.

Comment: Uff, thanks. Sounds a bit too complicated, but probably it is the only way.

Comment: Okay, I copied the view.phtml and the wrapper.phtml and wrapper/bottom.phtml and added own getChildHtml() calls - but of course now the whole template is duplicated and if an magento update changes something there, the changes are overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.addtocart">
        <block type="disablecartonlogout/output" name="disablecartonlogout.outputbefore" as="whatever1" before="-" template="disablecartonlogout/product-options-bottom-before.phtml" />
        <block type="disablecartonlogout/output" name="disablecartonlogout.outputafter" as="whatever2" after="-" template="disablecartonlogout/product-options-bottom-after.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

then go to:

`app\design\frontend\default\themeName\template\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml`

and add

```
$this->getChildHtml('whatever1', true, true);
$this->getChildHtml('whatever2', true, true);
```

Try this as it may help you. I tried something like this